# How to do an atomic transaction in gundb?

Tags: javascript, gun

How do I do an atomic commit/transaction in GUN? https://gun.eco/docs/Transactions is a bit opaque.

I need to do multiple puts and ensure they are (eventually) executed all together without intervening changes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the callback in `put` to be sure it has completed:

https://gun.eco/docs/API#-a-name-put-a-gun-put-data-callback-

```
let gunput = (val) => { return new Promise((res,rej) => {
    gun.get('something').put(val, function(ack){
       if(ack.err){
          res(false)
       }
       res(true)
    })
}
let tx_done = await gunput('test')
if (tx_done) // do next tx
```

Comment: This would allow a single client to wait for multiple puts to resolve, but does not ensure that if one put fails, all the rest should fail.

The question is mainly about dealing with concurrency when there are multiple peers that may be writing to the same data.

Comment: @RaineRevere hmm perhaps there is some way you could use "frozen" (hash identified) space, then it would not matter if there were multiple writes